# Correct call for Parallel For Each C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method signature similar to below:

```
private void MyMethod(List<MyObject> myObjects, string test)
```

I want to call this method in a parallel.for each but not sure how I should be passing the string parameter?

Currently my call looks like:

```
Parallel.ForEach(myObjects, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5}, MyMethod);
```

what is the correct way to call this passing both parameters?

Comment: What use is `test` in the loop if you were to write it in a non-parallel way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MyMethod` should only take one parameters of type `MyObject` (instead of `List<MyObject>`).

So it should have this signature

```
private void MyMethod(MyObject myObjects, string test)
```

After that, you just need to add a wrapper if you want to add an additionnal parameters

```
Parallel.ForEach(myObjects,
new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5},
x => MyMethod(x,test));
```